# CSV files into SQL using Blobtrigger and Sqlbulkcopy

Tags: c#, sql, azure-functions

Im writing a blobtrigger that takes CSV files from a blob and inserts it into SQL using SqlBulkCopy.

I have about 20 predefined tables in the db.

My problem is that alot of the tables in the db have date formatted columns.
So when i try to insert my files using a DataTable i get an exception (since DataTable columns is automatically formatted as strings i guess).

I have been googling around and all i can find is hard-coded examples using SqlBulkCopy mappings. Since i have about 20 different files which eventually can be moore i really dont want to write a shitloads of if-statements or create 20 dto´s.

So im wondering if there is any magic way to solve my issue in a smooth fashion?

Here is my basic blobtrigger code:

```
       [FunctionName("BlobTriggerFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("myTrigger", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudBlockBlob blob, TraceWriter log)
    {           
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        var fileName = blob.Name;

        if (!fileName.EndsWith(".CSV"))
        {
            log.Info($"Blob '{blob.Name}' doesn't have the .csv extension. Skipping processing.");
            return;
        }
        //Read csv
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await blob.OpenReadAsync()))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
            {
                dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(dr);
            }
        }
        //Do some stuff with the data, nothing importent
        var data = new PrepareDataTable(dataTable, fileName);
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DWHConnString")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = data.TableName;
                    await sqlBulk.WriteToServerAsync(data.Table);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        //Delete blob
        await blob.DeleteAsync();

    }
}
```

Appreciate all help i can get,

Thanks!

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750653/sql-bulkcopy-yyyymmdd-problem . hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that while preparing data table, you can look for date column in every single row and you can convert it to required format.
Then you don't need to worry about the format exception which is ideal too.